# How to omit undesired characters while parsing a line from a file in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

**The Problem:**
I am given a .dat file with 3 columns of 100 data (id number, object weight, object value) which are separated by some spaces/tabs (see below). For the purposes of my assignment in a class on Markov Models, I simply rewrote all of these data into a 3x100 array to use for my simulations. However, if the list were any longer, I would not be able to do this step by hand, so I would like to learn how to properly read in each line of the .dat file such that each of the data values is put into a (100x3) 2-dimensional matrix/list called "data'. To reiterate, this is nowhere related to the homework assignment, I just wish to understand the best way to input such a hypothetically large data file efficiently with python 3.

First eight lines of the .dat input file are below. The formatting posted differently than it looks when copied into the question box, but I don't want to edit it for the sake of formatting in case that is relevant to the problem.

```
%%id     weight (metric tons)    value (1000 USD) 
1    45220           28312 
2    38764           22635 
3    24801           21689 
4    4507            22864 
5    57671           12037 
6    64263           15571 
7    59482           1618
```

After reading other answers relating to parsing in python, I believe that I should begin with a structure similar to what I have below.

```
with open('Packing.dat') as f:
    for line in f:
        for i in range(len(line)):
            #functionThatMovesDownLineAndDistributesData(char)
```

What I would like to learn how to do is parse through each of the data lines, ignore all the spaces between the data, and distribute the three data types into a 2-dim array to use for later processing.

1. How do I ignore anything that isn't a number as I move down the line?
2. How do I set up a system that knows when a particular datum is done being parsed and ready to be added to the 2-dim matrix? The values are not always the same size, but they *are* always separated by at least one space/tab.

Thank you very much for anyone willing to offer some assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following. I am iterating through the file skipping the first line, then parsing out the integers and saving them to a list.
[string.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) splits line into multiple elements, taking more than one whitespace into account
e.g.

```
line = '1    45220           28312'
print(line.split())
#['1', '45220', '28312']
```

```
datas = []
with open('Packing.dat') as f:
    #Ignore the first line with column description
    next(f)
    #Iterate through lines in the file
    for line in f:
        data = []
        #Get all elements in each line in a list
        items = line.split()
        #Append these elements to a list
        for item in items:
            data.append(int(item))
        #Append the elements list to a bigger list
        datas.append(data)
print(datas)
#[[1, 45220, 28312], [2, 38764, 22635], [3, 24801, 21689], [4, 4507, 22864], [5, 57671, 12037], [6, 64263, 15571], [7, 59482, 1618]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But I don't quite understand what is happening. Does items = line.split() break the line up into each of its individual characters? When the individual values are being appended to data, where does the distinction between categories occur? Reading this code, I would think that the output would be [[14522028312], [23876422635], ...].